# Java Scanner Asks For The Input Twice

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to detect how many numeric values the input includes first by using "theCounter" method that I write, then I want to add these numeric values into an array so I use "theCounter" for the size of the array. However my codes requires to write input twice instead of once.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class ConverterApp {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        System.out.print("Enter a unity to convert: ");
        Scanner theInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] theValues = new double[ theCounter(theInput.nextLine()) ];

        while ( theInput.hasNextDouble() ) {

            for( int i = 0; i < theValues.length; i++ ) {

                theValues[ i ] = theInput.nextDouble();
            }

            if ( !theInput.hasNextDouble() ) {

                break;
            }

        }
        theInput.close();
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(theValues));



    }

    public static int theCounter( String input ) {

        int count = 0;
        boolean previousDigit = false;

        for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {

            if ( Character.isDigit( input.charAt( i ) ) ) {

                if ( !previousDigit ) {

                    count++;
                    previousDigit = true;

                }

            }
            else {

                previousDigit = false;
            }

        }

        return count;
    }                                                                  
}
```

A sample output:

```
Enter a unity to convert: 10 11 l
10 11 l
[10.0, 11.0]
```

What I want to see:

```
Enter a unity to convert: 10 11 l
[10.0, 11.0]
```

I am also open solutions about arrays, I mean a way to do what I want without detecting the size of the array or another way to do this.

Thanks in advance. :)